# display picture with php

Tags: php, mysql, image

now i need to show the picture of the product, which is named with the id number. doesnt work like this:

```
 $cat_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - <img src=inventory_images/'$id'.jpg"> <br />";
```

how am i supposed to do it !??!
it doesnt work like that, the whole code is this:

```
<?php 
$cat_list="";
$cat=$_GET['cat'];
$cat_sql="SELECT * FROM products,prod_cat,categories WHERE categories.id=prod_cat.cat_id AND products.id=prod_cat.prod_id AND categories.id=$cat";
$cat_query=mysql_query($cat_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($cat_query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cat_query)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $cat_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> -&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well what URL is the image supposed to exist at?

Comment: inventory_images/$id.jpg

Comment: I see multiple " in the first string, does it run without errors? Try  `echo '... - <strong>' . $product_name . '</strong> - <img src=inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg"> <br />';`

Comment: you have sql injection on `$_GET['cat']`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors in your $cat_list string:

```
$cat_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg'> <br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet can't work due to improperly set quotations. Change it to

```
$cat_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg'> <br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - <img src=\"inventory_images/$id.jpg\"> <br />";
```

you forget to put " qoute after `src=` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not echoing anything.

```
$cat_list="";
$cat=$_GET['cat'];
$cat_sql="SELECT * FROM products,prod_cat,categories WHERE categories.id=prod_cat.cat_id AND products.id=prod_cat.prod_id AND categories.id=$cat";
$cat_query=mysql_query($cat_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($cat_query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cat_query)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             echo 'Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - <img src="inventory_images/'.$id.'.jpg" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$cat_list = "";
 $cat = $_GET['cat'];
 $cat_sql="SELECT * FROM products,prod_cat,categories WHERE categories.id=prod_cat.cat_id AND products.id=prod_cat.prod_id AND categories.id=$cat";

$cat_query = mysql_query($cat_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($cat_query); // count the output amount

if ($productCount > 0) {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cat_query)) { 
     
          $id = $row["id"];
                           $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                            $ext = "jpg" ;
                           echo sprintf('Product ID: %s - **%s** -       
', $id , $product_name , %id , $ext);
    }
}

please make sure image extention is jpg,if not then replace the value of $ext variable